# Removing characters from autocomplete

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove everything after (and including) a `,` when clicking on something on my autocomplete.

So far I have tried this:

```
select: function(event, ui) { 
var str = $("#site_search").val(ui.item.label); 
this.value = str.split(",")[0];     
return false;
```

Unfortunately all I get is: `TypeError: str.split is not a function` ?

Edit: Should have made it more clear, in my autocomplete list it shows results like:

`Hello, World`

When selecting something, in the text field it should say only `Hello`

Comment: I don't get this line? `var str = $("#site_search").val(ui.item.label);`

Comment: try `this.value = str.val().split(",")[0];`

Comment: `var str` is not the actual string but the element `$('#site_search')`.

Comment: Playing with that line, I found out what it does actually. It sets the value of the element and then returns the element itself to the variable. Quite confusing. http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/9myyjk09/

Comment: Thanks @PranavCBalan that did it, if you want to post it as answer, I would accept it.

Comment: @putvande `.val(value)` will return the jQuery object not the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `val()`

```
select: function(event, ui) { 
var str = $("#site_search").val(ui.item.label); 
this.value = str.val().split(",")[0];
//            --^--     
return false;
```

`$("#site_search").val(ui.item.label);` will return the jQuery object  and not the string.

**[Documentation : val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value)**

Comment: Or split that line in two. One setting the value and the other one, getting it and putting in the variable. It would make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this line `var str = $("#site_search").val(ui.item.label);` is wrong. Because `.val('somevalue')` returns jQuery object which doesn't have a `split` method.

You should instead use:

```
var str = $("#site_search").val();
```

#### For clarity

```
.val(); //getter; returns String
.val('somevalue'); //setter; returns the jQuery element
```

Comment: Actually, the `.val()` is exactly to return the value of the object. It's returning the object itself because in the same line the OP is setting that value.

Comment: @MelanciaUK ah! Yes. I didn't use the "somevalue" part.